# Checking if folder exists or checking username in database, which is faster and better?

Tags: php

Any time a user is registered, a folder (based on their sanitized/validated username) is created for each user.

I want to know which is better and faster to check if user exists

```
<?php
 if( file_exists($user_folder) ){
 echo 'Username already exist. Choose another one';
}
?>
```

or checking database to check if username exists?

Comment: Depends on the local configuration: same machine filesystem/DB, network, ...

Comment: DB seems to be safest and also performant if you index the username column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a file system is the slowest thing possible. Databases on the other hand might store their indices in RAM, which is a lot faster to get access to. So I'd prefer database approach. But to reach maximum performance you need to make sure whether the table field with username is set as `UNIQUE` so DB will have an index with all usernames (if you're using relational databases like MySQL, Postgres, etc.)

Also, a few words regarding `file_exists()` function. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), it caches its results to work faster, but no one knows what username will be registered next time, so DB is better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think its depend on the **data** and **database design** you have.
But if you use index(unique) on username, database will be faster. Its all about the searching algorithm.

Lets say you have *1.000.000 users*. And you are checking the folder, it will check **one by one**, but if you check using database it will **go direct the data** by username. Because databases searching algorithms are very advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the database method (best and secure) instead of folder searching. So If you didn't add `index` in your **users** table then add index for fastest searching by -
`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name (column);`

#### Edit :

**Use cases -**

- If you are storing username as a text and user's profile pic as `BLOB` in the same table then must use `SELECT username` instead of `SELECT *`.